# How to compare user input with text file using strcmp in C?

Tags: c, string, io, strcmp

I have a problem when comparing two of the same strings in C. Using the method strcmp(), there seems to be a problem when comparing a line from a text file to the user input. Why does strcmp() return -1 even if user input is identical to the text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <string.h>

struct Person{
    char fName[10];
    char lName[10];
};

char inputUser[10]; 

int main()
{   
   FILE *file;
   int ret;
   char data[20];

   file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
   struct Person *p1 =  malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
   gets(inputUser);

   strcpy(p1->fName , inputUser);
   struct Person *p2 =  malloc(sizeof(struct Person));

   while (fgets(data , 20 , file) != NULL){
      strcpy(p2->fName , data);
      ret = strcmp(p1->fName, p2->fName);
      printf("\t%d\t%s\t%s\n", ret , p1->fName, p2->fName);
   }
   fclose(file);
   file = fopen("file.txt","a"); 
   fprintf(file, "%s\n", p1->fName);  
   fclose(file);

}
```

Comment: Have you considered the *newline* issue ? with `gets` and `fgets` ? why not use `fgets(inputUser,20,stdin)` instead of `gets(inputUser)` ?

Comment: Your question requires sample input, expected output, and actual output before it is a [mcve].

Comment: note that  input of the fgets  the result will include a trailing newline. remove the newline if newline is exist.

Comment: Note that [you should never use the `gets()` function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) — it is too dangerous.  It removes the newline from what it reads; `fgets()` does not.  Comparing a string with a newline and a string without a newline will always yield a difference.

Comment: Hey @craexus, if my answer (or another) has helped you, would you consider accepting it? Accepting an answer shows the community that it has solved your problem, and helps future readers with theirs. If you don't know how to accept an answer, there's a useful [faq meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this after your `gets(inputUser)`:

```
inputUser[strlen(inputUser)-1] = '\0';
```

That will remove the  last character of the string. `gets()` records the newline (Enter key) the user inputs. That's why `strcmp()` doesn't think they're the same thing, because of the newline.

Also, to avoid a Segmentation Fault, you should change `gets(inputUser)` to:

```
fgets(inputUser, sizeof(inputUser), stdin);
```

This does the same thing except the second argument limits the length of the data that can  be read. With `gets()`, if you enter over 10 characters to be stored in a 10-character string it will seg-fault.

Comment: `inputUser[strlen(inputUser)-1] = '\0';` is sufficient for learning programs, but allows a hacker exploit of a user entering a null character as the first character of input.  That results in `inputUser[(size_t)-1] = '\0';` which is UB and likely an exception.  Suggest http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2410359

Comment: `fgets(inputUser, sizeof inputUser, stdin);` is not a problem.   `fgets()` does not need a `-1` to avoid seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
  strcpy(p2->fName , data);
  ret = strcmp(p1->fName, p2->fName);
```

by

```
  strcpy(p2->fName , strtok(data, "\n"));
  ret = !strcmp(p1->fName, p2->fName);
```

- !strcmp(A, B) returns true (1) if A equals B. Otherwise returns false (0);
- strtok(A, B) returns A without the substring B.